# Change header name for each column in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data with ID's and their qualification such as certifications, Advance degree only, Multiple degrees and Single certification in a Yes/No format

I am trying to show the data in 4 bar charts like 1) No Certifications (3) 2) Only Advance Degree (6) 3) Single certifications (17) and 4) Multiple Degree (19). Counts are mentioned in the bracket.

I need to rename each column with the above-mentioned header name. However, if change name of one column, the other column name also changes. Kindly suggest adding an individual name for each column.

The graph looks like below.

[image]

```
ID  Certifications  AdvanceDegree only  Single Cert  MutipleDegree
1       Yes                No                No         Yes
2       Yes                No                Yes        No
3       Yes                No                No         Yes
4       Yes                No                No         Yes
5       Yes                No                No         Yes
6       Yes                No                No         Yes
```

Comment: Would suggest that a `CASE` statement with an `OR` - alternatively you could pivot your data, are you able to share a sample workbook?

Answer (score 0):

You can define aliases for the members of your discrete dimension fields to display more meaningful strings. For example, right click on the field Certifications in the data pane (left margin sidebar), edit the aliases and use "Has Certifications" as an alias for Yes, and "No Certifications" as an alias for No.

If you want something other than simply relabeling your current columns, you could define calculated fields to independently count records, for instance, a field like **[Num Advanced Degree]** as `Count(if [AdvanceDegree only] = "Yes" then 1 end)` Don't add an else in this case.

Its safer and usually more efficient to work with Boolean fields instead of Strings so if you are using Excel for instance, change your YES values to TRUE and No values to FALSE in your spreadsheet.

In that case, you simply drop the `= "YES"` part of the previous calculation